# Invalid column name using sp_MSForEachDB in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-msforeachdb

I am attempting to query multiple databases housed on the same SQL Server instance using sp_MSForEachDB.

There are 8 databases that have the table man_days with a column named servicetype. I have manually verified that all 8 tables are identical.

When run the following query I get the error message **Invalid column name 'servicetype'**

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''man_days'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''servicetype'')
        SELECT top 1 [man_days].[servicetype] from [?]..[man_days]
END
'
```

The result set is as expected however the error keeps coming up. What am I doing wrong?

Edit... If I change the code to query all columns as in the code below, it works without issue. Or if I change it to query other single columns within that table it works without issues. It only fails when I attempt to select that one column

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''man_days'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''servicetype'')
        SELECT top 1 * from [?]..[man_days]
END
'
```

[[image: Result Set]] [1][image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think the issue might be a compilation issue.  Try this rather alternative

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''man_days'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''servicetype'')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @sql = ''SELECT top 1 [man_days].[servicetype] from [db]..[man_days]'';
        REPLACE(@sql, ''[db]'', ?);
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END;
END
';
```

That is, turn the `SELECT` into dynamic SQL, so it is not evaluated at the same time as the `IF`.

Comment: I changed your code slightly and it works perfectly. If I am understanding the fix properly, then the procedure was not properly adding the correct database to the query? *****
```code 
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''man_days'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''servicetype'')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @sql = ''SELECT top 1 [man_days].[servicetype] from [db]..[man_days]''
        SET @sql = REPLACe(@sql, ''[db]'', ''[?]'');

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END;
END';
```

Comment: @JeremiahNelson . . . Not exactly.  The change is that the code is dynamic SQL so it is compiled when it is executed.  That prevents the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess it is permissions on the metadata for one or more of the databases.

The visibility of the metadata in information schema views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission. For more information, see [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/metadata-visibility-configuration?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15).

It may be the specific permission that your login then has on that table that restricts whether you can see the column names. VIEW DEFINITION permission I think will be required so that this error isn't shown.

Comment: Would this be case if I can query the tables individually without issue? Also, while I do not have admin access to the server or instance, I do have db_owner permissions to the databases themselves.

Comment: I would expect that "should" probably allow you to then see the info.  Can you query  ```SELECT * FROM <DB>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'man_days' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'servicetype'``` for each database directly and get the correct result?

Comment: Yes, your test returns a row of data. I also used the example from the link you gave and was able to create and run the following stored procedure without issue. ```CREATE PROCEDURE assumes_caller_can_access_metadata  
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT name, object_id   
FROM sys.objects   
WHERE name = N'man_days';  
END;  
GO  ```

Comment: Interestingly, if I query the entire table via * in my same original code, it works perfectly. Its only gives the error if I tell it to specifically grab servicetype.

Comment: Do any of your databases use a Case Sensitive collation?   And if so, is the column name always all lower case?

Comment: None of the databases use Case Sensitive collation. As a double check, I just verified that all the columns were all lower case. As an additional test I just cycled though all databases individually using the exact same code as posted and they all get the same error. ```EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'USE [?]; IF DB_NAME() IN (''WestCoast'')
BEGIN
SELECT top 1 ''[?]'' as x, [servicetype] from [?].dbo.man_days
END
' ```

Comment: Odd.  Without having access to your databases I can't think of anything else to check for.  I assume ```EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''man_days'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''servicetype'')
        SELECT top 1 [servicetype] from [?].[dbo].[man_days]
END
'  ```  also errors?     There isn't a [man_days] table in a different schema is there?

Comment: Yes it fails. Thanks for trying.

Comment: My only other suggestion is to configure an Extended Events trace on each DB to capture the actual T-SQL executed and see if there is any odd behaviour coming through that would explain it.